# Openerp RML Report Print on Menu

Tags: odoo

How to print rml report by clicking on menu in openerp?
Without opening any wizard.
Is i have to make any action and return on menu click action? Please explain with example.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the report with a `<report>` tag. Here's an example from the [OpenERP documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/05_reports.html#the-xml-definition).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
        <data>
                <report
                        id="report_sale_order"
                        string="Print Order"
                        model="sale.order"
                        name="sale.order"
                        rml="sale/report/order.rml"
                        auto="False"
                        header="False"/>
        </data>
</openerp>
```

Before you're ready to do that, you'll need to create the [report file](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/05_reports.html#openoffice-org-reports) and the [parser](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/05_reports.html#parser). The core modules all use SXW report files to generate RML files, and then run the report from the RML files. Personally, I prefer to just work directly with the RML files. There's also a [Mako template engine](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/05_reports.html#html-reports-using-mako-templates), but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot Don Kirkby for your valuable reply !!! :) I will try :) I am new to openerp and python. I don't know in detail how openerp manager report. :( If you can provide me any doc or guide then, it is best for me

Comment: Follow the links in my answer, @user1529289, and look at some examples in the core modules, like the sales order. The file is `openerp-addons/sale/report/order.rml`, I think.